# Issue with nested For/Next loop and filling array

Tags: vba, excel

I am working in VBA assignment and need to make an array that auto populates the values 16 to 9 in reverse order. this is my current code:

```
nTeams = 16                     ' variable to enable other size brackets

ReDim arrBracket(nTeams / 2) '<< ReDim array to appropriate size


'***** Fill the array where element 1 of the array holds the value of the
'      lowest seed (e.g. if 16 teams, element 1 has a value of 16)

' vvv your For/Next loop below
Dim nTeams2 As Integer ' Place holder for For/Next loop

For i = 1 To (nTeams / 2)
    For nTeams2 = nTeams To (nTeams / 2) Step -1
        arrBracket(i) = nTeams2
    Next nTeams2
Next i
```

The issue is that it now is only filling the array with the number 8 for each of the 8 elements, rather than 16, 15, 14, 13, etc.

Here is the loop my professor included to check the work:

```
For i = LBound(arrBracket()) To UBound(arrBracket())    ' loops through the array
    Debug.Print i & " vs " & arrBracket(i)              ' sends array info to immediate window
Next i
```

Comment: You don't need to use the inner loop. What is happening is what you are assigning different values multiple times to the same position in the array. The last one is always 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to set nested loops for that. You can do that only with inner for loop. Here you go.

```
nTeams = 16                     ' variable to enable other size brackets

ReDim arrBracket(nTeams / 2) '<< ReDim array to appropriate size

Dim i As Integer
Dim nTeams2 As Long

i = 0
For nTeams2 = nTeams To (nTeams / 2) Step -1
    arrBracket(i) = nTeams2
    i = i + 1
Next nTeams2
```

Comment: modify your line of `i = 1` to `i=0`, otherwise your code will get "Subscript out of range" since you are getting to arrBracket(9) which doesn't exist